# No sound when play video stream in HTML5

Tags: html5-video, html5-audio, vlc, vlcj

I am using vlc player to transcode multicast stream and then showing using HTML5 video tag. Video is playing there but i unable to get any sound.

VLC command:

```
vlc udp://@192.168.1.1 --sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=1024,channels=1,ab=128,samplerate=44100,width=320}:http{dst=:8080/webcam.ogg}
```

here is the html:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" width="500px" preload="metadata" controls>  <source src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/webcam.ogg"/><source src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/webcam.ogg"/></video>
```

However same stream (http://127.0.0.1:8080/webcam.ogg) is playing with proper sound in vlc player. Can someone suggest me where is the problem.

Comment: Your sout string specifies a video codec but no audio codec...

Comment: Can you please give me hint which audio codec i need to use there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying an audio codec in your transcoding string, here are some examples (originally taken from some demo code in the VLC sources):

```
#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{cfr=16},scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{cfr=40},scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=96,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
#transcode{vcodec=theo,venc=theora{quality=9},scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
#transcode{vcodec=theo,venc=theora{quality=4},scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=96,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=2000,scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=1000,scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=96,channels=2,samplerate=44100}
```

Which particular one you need is up to you and your requirements.

Comment: Perfect, by adding "acodec=vorb" stream now play with sound :) inside HTML video tag..  Can you please tell me one thing for my understanding, Why Stream was playing with sound inside vlc player when i was transforming without adding audio codec and play as a network stream in vlc but fail to given sound inside HTML video tag ?

Comment: VLC must be adding default options for you.